# Leaflet markercluster: How can I change the bounds of the markercluster?

Tags: json, leaflet, markerclusterer, mkcoordinateregion, leaflet.markercluster

For university I create a webmap using leaflet - it´s about migration in Iraq. In the map I have one choropleth-layer with coordinates from a json (Iraq with its gouvernorates) with a value for each gouvernorate. Additionally I added a layer with markers from another json to the map. This json only contains the coordinates for markers with a value for each marker. I implemented a leaflet markerclustering where all child markers are summarized and the sum is shown in the parent-icon - although the sum isn´t correct until now, I think it is working, so far... I am allready looking for the mathematical error...

Now, I would like to change the bounds for the marker-clustering (currently I think they are built automatically and randomly by leaflet) to the bounds of the gouvernorates in the first json of Iraq. The aim is a regionbound clustering for the gouvernorates of Iraq. There are some examples on the web and I have tried a lot, but it doesn´t work... 
maybe somebody here can help me.. If you have any questions or need further explanation, just tell me!

Sources:
- json code in an js-file "iraq_09_14.js" with the gouvernorate-polygon-coordinates of Iraq

- json code in an js-file "target-location_09_14.js" with marker-polygones and value for each marker

[this is the js-code where I create the leaflet map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9tke.jpg)

[this is the js-code where I create the markerclusters with the sum of the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj00O.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to change the bounds for the marker-clustering [...] to the bounds of the gouvernorates in the first json of Iraq.

Then create one instance of `MarkerClusterGroup` per governorate, and add each marker to the corresponding cluster group.

> This json only contains the coordinates for markers with a value for each marker.

You should really pre-process the data, so each marker has information about what governorate it belongs to. You might want to do point-in-polygon geoprocessing, via Turf or otherwise.

> (currently I think [the clusters] are built automatically and randomly by leaflet)

They are not random, the hierarchical greedy clustering algorithm is deterministic. You can read more at https://www.mapbox.com/blog/supercluster/

Comment: Thank´s Ivan! Now I pre-processed the marker-data and created an instance for each governorate and everything works..

Comment: Glad to hear that! Remember to [set the question as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).